# JQuery error on .load - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread

Tags: jquery

I have this function in jquery which uses .load to open a page in a popup div:

```
function LoadModal(page, title) {
    title = title || '';

    $( "#modal_page" ).fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#modal_title" ).html(title);

    $("#modal_page_body").html('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>'); //$('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $("#modal_page_body").load(page, function(){

    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

when i call this function, my console is showing this error:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try use `$.ajax()` and add an `ajaxPrefilter()`

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.async = true;
});

$.ajax({
     url: page,
     success:function(data) {
        // make an action after call is finished
        $("#modal_page_body").html(data); 
      }
 })
```

Comment: what is page url? json or other?